# Get OpenVPN gateway address

Tags: networking, ip, openvpn, ip-address, gateway

After connecting to a SSL VPN server, it assigns me an IP address. And it also gives me a gateway in the same network, I can use to connect to other networks reachable through the VPN tunnel.

For example I get the IP 10.10.10.5/24 and the gateway is 10.10.10.1 which allows me to reach the 10.10.11.0/24 network.

I know that the gateway will be in the same network as the client, so an alternative idea would be checking all gateway addresses and checking which one matches/is in the network.

Comment: I don't get what the question is; you say you are given the gateway, so what is the problem?

Comment: @wurtel it will change. And I don’t know what it’s address will be in the future.